# H.264 / H.265 Compression of a single Bitmap-Image

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, compression, h.264, h.265

I hope someone can help me.

I started researching different compression methods to compress Bitmap-Images lossless and lossy. The first methods i used were JPEG, JPEG-2000 and JPEG-XR. Now i want to compare these "standard" ones with H.264 and H.265, maybe they perform as well as they do for video compression.

I tried using ffmpeg, but i can't find out which parameters i need, there are plenty... So maybe someone can help me or link me to an Article/Howto or something else?!

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**:

I used the following command: 
ffmpeg -i 01.bmp -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 40 test.avi

but this created an 7kb file from an 76,8 kb input file... not very good compression ratio... is there any possibility to achieve more?

Comment: Why did ffmpeg not work? (because it should have) Can you post the command you tried, and the results?

Comment: The problem is that i don't know exactly which parameters to apply. Which one do i need to control the quality? Or is it possible to pass an parameter giving the output size?

Comment: I used the following command: ffmpeg -i 01.bmp -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 40 test.avi, but this created an 7kb file from an 76,8 kb input file... not very good compression ratio... is there any possibility to achieve more?

Comment: I now changed the fileextension of the output to ".h264", now the file is compressed pretty good!!! Is it correct to use this extension? Is another one event better?

Comment: .h264 or .264 are common

Answer (score 0):

"-crf 40" will choose bitrate around QP = 40, that is somehow low visual quality.
For H.264, QP = 0 ~ 51, where 0 is the best.
So you can consider use "-crf = 16", or even smaller number.
I believe the quality will be much better.